# How to return a List from a Custom widget using a function? like onchanged in a radiobutton

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom widget for multi selection of items. I want to return that List in a parameter of a function.

**Here is my Model**

```
class Model {
 String id;
 String name;

 Model({this.id, this.name});

 Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  id = json['id'];
  name = json['name'];
 }

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
  data['id'] = this.id;
  data['name'] = this.name;
  return data;
 }
}
```

**Widget calling**

```
class Main extends StatelessWidget {
 List<Model> data = [
  Model(id: '1', name: 'value1'),
  Model(id: '2', name: 'value2'),
  Model(id: '3', name: 'value3'),
  Model(id: '4', name: 'value4'),
  Model(id: '5', name: 'value5'),
 ];

 List<Model> finalDataList = <Model>[];

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  body: CustomMultiSelect(){
  dataList: data,
  function(value){
   finalDataList.addAll(value);
  },
 },);
}
```

I want to get selected items from list when i click on button (designed in widget).

Comment: Can you add your widgets structure to the question?

Comment: paste CustomMultiSelect codes, please.